# Work with objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I need to work with objects in NSMutableArray. I have NSMutableArray called "Albums"
it contains objects "Album"

```
@interface Album : NSObject {   
    NSString *aid;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *ownerID;
}
```

I push few Album objects into "Albums" NSMutableArray, and i want to delete Album object where
"title" field is "HelloWorld" for example or something else. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
NSArray *matchingObjects = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.title = %@", @"HelloWorld"]];
[array removeObjectsInArray:matchingObjects];
```

Comment: And one more, how to pass fiew params into  "predicateWithFormat"

Comment: for example i have 2 same album.titles but different album.aid
and i want to make matchingObjects by aid and title to get only necessary album 
is this possible?

Comment: [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) you should find all you need. In your case you'd simply change the string to "self.title = %@ AND self.aid = %@" and add your aid as an additional parameter to the end.